# How to get a database for 1 table with 1 username and 1 score on Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just need a database for 1 table. To keep names and scores and the names are the primary key.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scoreboard);
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores(_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,score INTEGER);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (_id, score) VALUES ('DARR',99);");
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores;",null);

    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        buffer.append("Player: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Score: "+c.getInt(1)+"\n");
    }
    String result = buffer.toString();

    TextView scoreRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewScoreResult);
    scoreRes.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: How wrong? Are there levels of wrong? Very wrong. Joking aside, what's the error that you're getting? Also you need to update the title of your question, 'Help me!' might be a little too generic :-)

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: ok excuse me, first post. Its a database for the highscores of a game. So each device users app would check their highest score against the database, If thiers featured in the top five it would replace whats in the database. But thats skipping ahead. For now i just want a database with 1 username and 1 score.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, SharedPreferences solves your need. Use the name as 'key' and the score as 'value' to the SharedPreferences.

For more info, refer http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Do not use SQLite database unless the app really needs it.

Comment: Your answer is as vague as the question itself. How would you store multiple scores inside SharedPreferences? Why is it better for the OP's needs?

Comment: Yes. Multiple scores for a single name cannot be stored using SharedPreferences. I see that, he wants a single table to store a name and a score. The name is the key to save and retrieve the score. SharedPref solves this.

Comment: We should not have a mindset that the app requires the Database first, and then think about how to save our data. First see our data, and think about the ways to store our data.

Comment: I dont think there will be performance gains using one or the other. SQLite database could be used to have relational database. SharedPreferences could be used for simple key and value storage.